# Looking for a book involving a comet and blue skinned sailors

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been looking for a pulpy sci-fi book for literally 20 years with no luck. Maybe now is the time? I only read part of the book, but the part I remember goes something like:

A man wakes up the morning after a comet has passed near Earth. His entire neighborhood and the city of Los Angeles (I think?) are empty. He gets a car and heads to the coast. Along the way he finds one other living person. When they reach the coast, they see and flag down a boat, which turns out to be part of the Australian Navy. All of the sailors are alive, but their skin has turned blue.

Not much to go on, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Invaders From Rigel*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7453) aka *The Onslaught from Rigel* by [Fletcher Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher_Pratt), also the answer to the old question [What story has a man wake to find himself transformed into living metal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60532/what-story-has-a-man-wake-to-find-himself-transformed-into-living-metal) Maybe one of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?7453) will ring a bell. The story is available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/41049).

The alien spaceship is mistaken for a comet:

> "What is it? Am I crazy, are you, or are we both?"
>
> "Of course not. Greatest thing that ever happened. The big comet. They said she was radioactive, but most of 'em wouldn't believe it. Now look what it did." (Murray Lee remembered vaguely some newspaper palaver about a giant comet that was going to strike the earth—argument and counter-argument as to whether it would have a serious effect.) "Everybody's turned to metal; nize machinery, ate oop all de axle-grease. You need oil. Stick around."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Will you sit down and tell me consecutively what it's all about before I bash you?" asked Murray, petulantly. "Being turned into a machine is not the easiest thing in the world on one's temper; it upsets the disposition."
>
> "Some sort of a special extra radioactive gas storm connected with the comet, I think, though I can't be sure. It's made machines of all of us, now and forever more. We'll live on electric current after this and won't have to bother about little things like doctors if we can find a good mechanic. But it killed a lot of people. Come along, I'll show you."

Blue-skinned Australian sailors:

> "... His Majesty's Australian ship *Brisbane*, they say," said Murray. "Wait a minute, since they're so near, I think I can switch them over to the radiophone." He ticked the key a moment, then twisted more dials and leaned back as a full and fruity voice, with a strong English accent, filled the room.
>
> "Compliments of Captain Entwhistle of the Royal Australian Navy to the commander of the U. S. S. *Ward*, and can we arrange a meeting? The Comet appears to have done a good deal of damage in your part of the world and you are the first people we have encountered."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "Where's your microphone?" asked Ben. "Oh, there.... Compliments of Benjamin Franklin Ruby, temporarily in command of U. S. S. *Ward* to Captain Entwhistle of the Royal Australian Navy, and none of us are sailors. We just borrowed this ship, and if you want to see us you'll have to pick us up. We'll keep along the coast toward Cape May. Can you meet us?"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> They ceased speaking as the thin pennon of smoke, followed by two tall masts, became visible over the horizon. In a few minutes more the *Brisbane* swept up, swung a circle and came to rest near them, while out from her side dropped a boat that began to move toward them with dipping oars.
>
> A moment later she was alongside. Ben stepped out on the deck, and as he did so, there was a mutual exclamation of horrified amazement—for Captain Entwhistle of the Royal Australian Navy was as much flesh and blood as any man they had seen in the old days, but a pale blue in color, and all his sailors were of the same extraordinary hue.